# Data is not showing in table view

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I am new to iOS, and started with some tutorials. But when I try to display the content in `tableview`, it's not showing. I did all like they did in that tutorial. But still I was not able to display my contetnt in my table view.

Here my tutoial link : [My link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xrzuev4etdk)

Here my code :

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var nameArray = [AnyObject]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


        Alamofire.request("http://thecodeeasy.com/test/swiftjson.json").responseJSON { response in

            let result = response.result
            if let dict = result.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>{
                if let mainDict = dict["actors"] {
                    self.nameArray = mainDict as! [AnyObject]
                   self.tableView.reloadData()
                }

            }


             }
    }



     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return nameArray.count
    }

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as? CustomTableViewCell

        let title = nameArray[indexPath.row]["title"]
        cell?.ContentName.text = title as? String
        return cell!
    }

}
```

Comment: is it in swift 3.0 ?

Comment: YES ...........

Comment: Write Alamofire.request("http://thecodeeasy.com/test/swiftjson.json")
into viewdidappear instead of viewdidload

Comment: @sinha
 your need to enable NSAllowsArbitraryLoads into plist file. I just implement your API into a fresh project and find this issue.
Please check Answer section for Demo project and details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three possibilities that you are not getting data.
First, your app datasource is not set properly.
Please check image for that

[image]

Second, Paste your API code into viewDidAppear and check if it's working or not

============= Important ============

Third, is check your info.plist contain following code.
Because whenever you are making the internet call you should have this code into your info.plist file.

Right click on info.plist and open as source code

paste the following code

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Try to run the app.
Let me know if its working for you.

Please check the link for code  [click here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rdww93a6so97cdo/Load%20Table.zip?dl=0)

Thank you

Abhishek Sharma

Answer (score 0):

Try this in top of the viewDidLoad

```
self.tableView.delegate = self
self.tableView.dataSource = self
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you are using a `tableview` inside a view controller. You should set delegate and data source of this `tableview` to `self`.

Write these 2 lines in your view controller:

```
self.tableView.delegate = self
self.tableView.datasource = self
```

You can do that with XIB too.

If you have already done that or that Doesn't work, then try printing your `self.nameArray` and check if have expected data.